# selecting row in the list view pattern keeps changing

Tags: android

Hi guys I have a small problem,I have a ListView designed in my app that shows multiple rows and multiple columns,and when i click on the row i am storing the entire row values in an array list.when i selected the first row a before i got the values like,
{col5="abc",col4="shs"........}
and when i tried with different rows the pattern was same as above 
so i used it like this to get data seperately...

```
    //new LongOperation().execute();


    String text = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    String g=text.replace("{col5=","");
    String g1=g.replace(" col4=","");
    String g2=g1.replace(" col7=","");
    String g3=g2.replace(" col6=","");
    String g4=g3.replace(" col1=","");
    String g5=g4.replace(" col3=","");
    String g6=g5.replace(" col2=","");
    String g7=g6.replace(" col8=","");


    String val[] = g7.split(",");


   for(int m =0 ; m< val.length ; m++)
{
      Log.d("VALUE",val[m]);
      ar1.add(val[m]);
}

System.out.println(ar1);
```

but today when i selected the row from list view the pattern completely changed,now first i am getting col4 which is causing me problem....can some one please help so that on click of listview the pattern remains uniform?

come on guys just help me with this one or else tell me weather there is a solution for this one or i need to change the list view?

Comment: A ListView with columns? Why you don't use a GridView then?

Comment: No I thought using a ListViiew will be a Better a Solution..But can u please help me with the above question..

Comment: still waiting on your valuable suggestion..

Comment: can you post the value of text before any replacement you are doing.

Comment: [{col4=560027, SMT.SAHANA.D.S., 13022684, ,  col5=, SRILAKSHMI  PHARMACEUTICALS, LVO-30, LVO-}]...this is the text value

Comment: but the other day i got col5 at the start...so i need that to be uniform only one pattern for every click so that i can configure it correctly

Comment: {col4=560027, col2=SMT.SAHANA.D.S., col1=13022684, col6=, col5=, col3=SRILAKSHMI  PHARMACEUTICALS, col7=LVO-30, col8=LVO-}